# How to open/view log4php logs by Apache-Chainsaw logviewer?

Tags: php, logging

Is there any way to open log4php logs by Chainsaw logviewer?
If yes, can you explain it to me?

Comment: I disagree with closing this. These is a very relavent programming question. The Chainsaw log viewer is a programming tool. Log4Php is programming library

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the chainsaw compatible appender. I'm only famailiar with the log4net appender for chaninsaw.

This is the one we used to use:

```
  <!-- Appender used with Chainsaw -->
  <appender name="UdpAppender-Chainsaw" type="log4net.Appender.UdpAppender">
      <remoteAddress value="127.0.0.1" />
        <remotePort value="8999" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j">
        <locationInfo value="true" />
        </layout>
  </appender>
```

Comment: Hello Preet, somehow i could not login through my openid, all in all thanks for your comment, i agree with you, it is context